# Match two columns from two dataframes and add items from a third column if cells match

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, linguistics

I have two pandas dataframes with linguistic data, `oset` with the full data and `miscset` which is a subset of the full data. I am looking for a way of comparing two columns with strings from two different dataframes, and identify those rows that match. Then I would like to copy a *third* column from `oset` over to `miscset`for those columns that match. For example:

```
oset = pd.DataFrame({'some_items' : ['book', 'cat', 'deer', 'egg'], 
                     'root' : ['boks', 'kattuz', 'deuza', 'ajja']})
miscset = pd.DataFrame({'subset' : ['cat', 'egg']})
```

I would then like to match `cat`and `egg` because they are shared, and then create a new column `root` in `miscset` that contain `kattuz` and `ajja` on the appropriate rows of course.

I started with this:

```
for row in miscset['subset']:
    if row.isin(oset['some_items']):
```

But I reached a problem already here since you cannot use `.isin` with strings.

Has anyone got any suggestions what I could do instead or how to proceed?

**Edit:** I should perhaps add that in my real datasets, there are more columns in both overall that I do not wish to transfer, or that I wish to keep, so I simply want to add 5th column to `miscset` using the appropriate rows from the `root` column in `oset`.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1: Merge**

```
miscset = miscset.merge(oset, left_on='subset', right_on='some_items', 
    how='inner').drop(columns='some_items')
#  subset    root
#0    cat  kattuz
#1    egg    ajja
```

You can change the merge depending upon how you want to deal with cases where there is no match or multiple matches in `oset`

Answer (score 1):

Using `map`

```
miscset.assign(root=miscset['subset'].map(oset.set_index('some_items')['root']))

  subset    root
0    cat  kattuz
1    egg    ajja
```

Comment: Thanks! When trying this out on my real dataset, I got the error ```Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects```. What could cause this?

Comment: That means you're not giving me enough information.  The sample data you provided is not adequate to demonstrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: How would you extend this to map *two* columns and then add the third when the first two match?